# Get the child's props onClick in parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent `ButtonGroup` component and the child `buttonItem` component:

```
//ButtonGroup Component (Parent)

clicky(){
 //capture the props of the clicked button, ie, caption and disabled here.
}
render() {
  return (
    <div onClick={this.clicky}>
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
  )
}

//buttonItem component: 

render() {
  return (
    <button disabled={this.props.disabled}>{this.props.caption}</button>
  )
}

//final render
<ButtonGroupComponent>
  <buttonItem caption="Nothing"/>
  <buttonItem caption="Something" disabled={true}/>
  <buttonItem caption="Refresh"/>
</ButtonGroupComponent>
```

from the above code is there any way i can capture the props of the clicked child `buttonItem`?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need to merge `this.props.children` with your custom prop. So, I suggest you use [React.Children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) to operate with it. 
By the way, after adding new prop you need to return this child, so  [cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) will help you with this.

Inside import section of ButtonGroupComponent:

```
import React, { Children, Component, cloneElement } from 'react';
```

Its render function will look like this:

```
render() {  
    const childrenWithCustomHandler = Children.map(this.props.children, itemChild => {
       // Arguments of cloneElement (component, [customProps], [customChildren])
       return cloneElement(itemChild, { onClickItem: this.clicky })
     }
    );

    return <div>{childrenWithCustomHandler}</div>;
  }
```

And the code of `buttonItem` component will look like:

```
 return (
    <button
      disabled={this.props.disabled}
      onClick={() => {
        this.props.onClickItem({ ...this.props });
      }}
    >
      {this.props.caption}
    </button>
  )
```

I used [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator to clone the object, so if you will want to change props in your `clicky` function, the child won't be rendered.

Comment: this returns all the children, not the clicked one.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty was it useful for you?